# Animation com CSS

Tags: html, css, animação

É possível utilizar uma animação infinita porém com um tempo de intervalo?

Exemplo: realizar a animação + espera 10 segundos + e realiza novamente, e assim por diante.

É possível? Se sim, poderiam ajudar?

Answer (score 5):

Sim, em um exemplo mais prático, basta vc deixar a duração da animação com o dobro do valor que vc precisa, tipo 4 segundos de animação, sendo que só nos 2 primeiros segundo a animação acontece, e nos outros 2 segundo fica parada. Depois disso, no @keyframes, vc configura para toda a animação acontecer nos primeiros 50% (50% de 4s = 2s), logo nos primeiro 50% do tempo a animação acontece, e nos outros 50% fica parado.

Logicamente vc pode alterar esses valores, por exemplo se for 10s, sendo 1 segundo de animação, e 9 segundo parados no @keyframes sua animação tem que acontecer nos primeiro 10% do tempo, e depois fica 90% parado

Veja o exemplo, a animação tem tempo total de 4s, mas o elemento só se move por 2s (50%), depois fica mais 2s parado, totalizando 100%

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: nome 4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes nome {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma é fazer uma regra de 3 para calcular o tempo da animação e o tempo da pausa.

Digamos você queira que a animação dure **3 segundos** e dê uma pausa de **6 segundos**. Somando os dois dá um total de **9 segundos**.

Regra de 3:

```
> tempo total = 100%
> tempo animação = x%

> tempo total * x = tempo animação * 100
> x = (tempo animação * 100) / tempo total
```

O valor de `x` será a porcentagem inicial a partir de quando a animação ficará parada. Aplicando os valores na regra de 3:

```
> 9 = 100%
> 3 = x%

> 9x = 300
> x = 300/9
> x = 33.33
```

Então seu `@keyframes` ficaria assim:

```
@keyframes anima{
  33.33%, 100% {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}
```

**Teste:**

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    animation: anima 9s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes anima {
  33.33%, 100% {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> De `0%` até `33.32%` a animação levará 3 segundos, e de `33.33%` a
>   `100%` haverá a pausa de 6 segundos, totalizando os `9s` que você
>   especificou na propriedade `animation`.